# Undefined index X-Api-Key in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to post some data in json format and passing 'X-Api-Key' as header key. But my code always give notice of undefined index x-api-key. And no data is stored.
I am using cake php 2.x
Here is my php code

```
    public function checkXAPI() {

        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        //X-Api-key unidentified
        if($headers['X-Api-Key'] == 'AB5433GMDF657VBB'){
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }



public function beforeFilter(){

    $this->Auth->Allow(array('checkXAPI','Registerowner'));

    $headersNotAllowed = array('login', 'checkXAPI', 'register');

    $noSecurityAllowed = array('register');
    if(!in_array($this->request->action, $noSecurityAllowed)){
        $checkXAPI = $this->checkXAPI();
        if (!$checkXAPI) {
            $message = array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => __('wrong X-API')
            );
            echo json_encode($message);
            exit;
        } else {
            $headers = apache_request_headers();
            if(!in_array($this->request->action, $headersNotAllowed)){

                if (isset($headers['Id'])) {
                    $checkUserToken = $this->checkUserToken();
                    if (!$checkUserToken) {
                        $message = array(
                            'status' => false,
                            'message' => __('wrong User ID and User token combination')
                        );
                        echo json_encode($message);
                        exit;
                    }
                }  
            }  
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: If the below answer still doesn't answer your question, please post the actual request you're making with javascript/external call. (Include a screenshot of your network tab, and ensure the `X-Api-Key` header is being attached to the request.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$this->request->header('X-Api-Key')`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::header) instead:

```
public function checkXAPI() {
    return $this->request->header('X-Api-Key') === 'AB5433GMDF657VBB';
}
```